# Does the "?." operator do anything else apart from checking for null?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

As you might know, `DateTime?` does not have a parametrized `ToString` (for the purposes of formatting the output), and doing something like

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
string x;
if(dt != null)
    x = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

will throw

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

But, since C# 6.0 and the Elvis (`?.`) operator, the above code can be replaced with

```
x = dt?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

which.... works! Why?

Comment: After reading the answers, I can't help but feel that the real solution to your problem goes like, "Just use `dt.Value.ToString()` already"

Comment: Ya, just calling dt.Value.ToString() will blow up if dt is null; you definitely want to use the Elvis Operator, not only because it has an awesome name but because it handles the NULL check for you.  dt?.Value.ToString() essentially says 
"If dt is not null, then access it's Value property and convert it to a String; if it IS null, ignore the call and do nothing"

Comment: There was already a null check. So there would be no problem using `.Value` in this scenario.

Comment: user4650451, The whole point is that you _cannot_ say `dt?.Value` because while `Nullable<>` has a property called `Value`, the underlying type `DateTime` has no member called `Value`, and since `?.` when used on a `Nullable<>` does not access the members of the `Nullable<>` itself but instead the members of the struct "inside" it, `dt?.Value` makes no sense. However, if the underlying struct itself has a `Value` member, such as with a `KeyValuePair<int, int>? nullableKvp` (nullable key-value pair from `int` to `int`), can you see what `nullableKvp?.Value` is, compared to `nullableKvp.Value`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `Nullable<T>` is implemented in C# in a way that makes instances of that struct appear as nullable types. When you have `DateTime?` it's actually `Nullable<DateTime>`, when you assign `null` to that, you're setting `HasValue` to `false` behind the scenes, when you check for `null`, you're checking for `HasValue`, etc. The `?.` operator is just implemented in a way that it replaces the very same idioms that work for reference types also for nullable structs. Just like the rest of the language makes nullable structs similar to reference types (with regard to `null`-ness).

Answer (score 14):

***Short answer:***

`DateTime?` is only a sweet syntax for [`Nullable<DateTime>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't contain `DateTime`'s properties and method while ***the Elvis operator works on the not-Nullable `Nullable<DateTime>.Value`.***

---

***Explanation:***

The following code:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
string x;
if (dt != null)
    x = dt?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

When decompiles as `C# 5.0` yields the following result:

```
DateTime? nullable = new DateTime?(DateTime.Now);
if (nullable.HasValue)
{
    string str = nullable.HasValue ? nullable.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : null;
}
```

<sub>*Side note: the `string` seems declared inside the `if` is irrelevant because of hoisting at the `MSIL` level, and since the value is not used later on the decompiler shows it as if it was declared inside that `if` scope.*</sub>

As you see, and since `DateTime?` is only a sweet syntax for `Nullable<DateTime>`, `C#` has a specific reference for `Nullable<T>`s with the *Elvis operator*, making its return value ***the non-nullable T itself***.

***The result of the whole `Elvis operator` must be `Nullable`*** therefore, if you wanted to receive a non-`string` value it would have to be either `Nullable<T>` or a `ReferenceType` but this doesn't change the fact that if the operator has managed to get the `Nullable<DateTime>` value itself - the returned `DateTime` is not `Nullable<DateTime>` anymore.

Comment: Down voter please explain so I can improve my answer.

Comment: you should remove the `if` around the string assignment. It negates the ternary operator within.

Comment: No, since the `string` is not used later on, this is a compiler optimization. This is the actual decompiled code in reflector...

Comment: If you have tested for nullable.HasValue, why do you test for it again with the ternary operator. It will **ALWAYS** return the `nullable.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`, so the ternary operator is useless.

Comment: Again, ***THIS IS A DECOMPILATION***, I will edit to add the original source code if it will make it clearer.

Comment: Reformatted, do you understand why it looks like that now?

Comment: How did you produce that code? TryRoslyn gave me one with [string optimized away](http://goo.gl/cDVjFn) in weird manner (tho JIT should take care of it) - without optimization it was [more or less the same](http://goo.gl/kyKG6U)

Comment: I've used `Reflector` but notice you have asked for `Release` instead of `Debug`: [Here is the same one in Debug](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoAxgGwEMQQYAHAJwHsoLD1sBvbGVmFQ5MXGANyrAATGOkKQAFAEoWbZm3kwAIp1QAVMOlQB+GIOQwAvEpXrNAOgByVAO44FbFBUiwAHnfswwAMxji9MAEIjCGB8fEkPGBlI1hdDXWQtM1UqOGQnaHEAIkFBAHoAWQK8hFKELMl3VgBfbGqgA==)

Comment: I was just looking at debug code ;) Do you get same duplicate `dateTime.HasValue && dateTime.HasValue` on release with Reflector?

Comment: `TryRoslyn` also compiles the give source, `Reflector` takes an already compiled one, The `Debug`/`Release` compilation result is determined by the `Visual Studio` at my set-up.

Comment: Haha, compiled it with `Release` on `Visual Studio` now and it does give the same double check, missing optimization I guess...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Read the other comments, this is a ***decompilation***.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That is true, I just copied the code from the question. although I would expect the compiler to optimize it away anyway. To be fair the `JIT` probably optimizes it away, I didn't exmine the `assembly` code that is compiled from that.

Comment: JIT is almost smart. On `Release` it left only `DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now` from sample code :) With `WriteLine(x)` it removed only `if (dt != null)` as predicted. Nullable seems to be JITed away as well `x = dt?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` bytecode is different (shorter) when it is guaranteed to never be null than when it can randomly become null. Also branch prediction loves to put half of line after end of `if`` body, I am too sober to make sense of it tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Considering:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
string x;
if(dt != null)
    x = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Here `dt` is a `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` witch is not `IFormatable` and don't have a `ToString(string format)` method.

So it throw.

Now considering:

```
x = dt?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The `?.` is a syntactic sugar for:

```
dt.HasValue ? dt.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"): null
```

Here `dt.Value` is a `DateTime` witch is `IFormatable` and have a `ToString(string format)` method.

Finally the good way to write the first code in C# 5.0 is:

```
DateTime? dt = DateTime.Now;
string x;
if(dt.HasValue)
    x = dt.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```